# Revolut closing account abroad?

Tags: sweden, uk-residents, revolut

I opened my Revolut account 2 years ago in the UK (at that time it was only for residents in the UK). I moved last year to Sweden to study… I never informed Revolut.

My problem is that my passport expired, I live far away from Stockholm so it’s not easy to go there and renew my passport (specially now).

Revolut emailed me last week saying that they might close my account if I don’t provide my passport… What should I do?

If there wasn’t the coronavirus problem, I would go to the embassy get my passport and problem solved (or even fly back)… But I have been with people with symptoms and even though I don’t have symptoms myself, I am quarantining.

The way I see it I have the next options, providing:

- a non EU passport, which I hold.
- my Swedish id, which isn’t an EU Id (I think is only valid in Sweden).
- I have an NHS card which is still valid…

Should I omit the fact that I don’t reside in the UK now? I would be back in June but again, I don’t know how legal residence works… (I was abroad mostly in Sweden from august 2019 up to now…).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a travel question, but a question about banking. [Money.se] would probably be a better fit, but check their help centre for guidance before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go to an embassy to have you passport renewed?

Getting a bank account in Sweden is easy. I guess you already have a BankID and then you can sign up for Rocker using just your phone. For older banks it's more complicated as you might have to have a shady phone call (Nordea) or visit a branch office.

<strike>Get a bank account with another bank. A few months ago I visited branch offices of most large banks in the UK trying to open a bank account as a foreigner - Barclays was the easiest one to do it with (most turned me down as they saw no value in having me as a customer), but then you need proof of a UK address, like a gas bill.</strike>

Comment: The embassy is in stockholm which is far away from where I am. I reside in Sweden now...

Comment: Is a good idea, but it would look a bit suspicious for Revolut: metransfering out all my money out of Revolut with an expired passport? Maybe I thought of uploading my non EU passport to Revolut, and what to see what they say...

Comment: @mmm00 they'd probably not care - if you're able to transfer your money do it before the account is locked. Apparently it can take months for the account to be unlocked once locked (for other reasons) but it might be faster if it's just about the passport.